# Simple firewall in .net

Tags: .net, firewall

I want to try create a simple firewall which restricts applications from accessing the internet except for applications I allow. Like netlimiter.
So it would have to allow internet access for applications that are white listed and drop the connections for the rest.
Is this possible with c# or vb.net?
If it is possible can you please point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, as terR0Q said, you'll need to use C++ or another low-level programming language (by low-level I mean that it's close to machine code).

If you want to stick with .NET, your options are VERY limited. For one thing, you'll need to heavily use WinApi, which is not very convenient from .NET (though certainly not impossible) - you might want to consider using VC++ .NET - and you can try to use [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) for managed hooking. **Note that it is certainly not a good solution**, the [tutorial](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/releases/view/24401#DownloadId=61179) in fact warns you about using it in a security software:

> Unlike what some (commercial) hooking
>   libraries out there are advertising to
>   boost sales, user-mode hooking can
>   NEVER be an option to apply additional
>   security checks in any safe manner. If
>   you only want to “sandbox” a dedicated
>   process, you know well about, and the
>   process in fact doesn’t know about
>   EasyHook, this might succeed! But
>   don’t ever attempt to write any
>   security software based on user mode
>   hooking. It won’t work, I promise you…
>   This is also why EasyHook does not
>   support a so called “System wide”
>   injection, which in fact is just an
>   illusion, because as I said, with
>   user-mode hooks this will always be
>   impossible. But if you want to keep
>   this illusion you may stick with other
>   (commercial) libraries attempting to
>   do so…

Some other hints in the tutorial:

> You should consider purchasing the
>   PatchGuard API which will allow you to
>   write security apps based on kernel
>   mode interceptions. Kernel mode
>   hooking (or the PatchGuard API) is the
>   only option to apply additional
>   security checks. Since Windows Vista,
>   also the Windows Filtering Platform
>   and other Vista specific APIs will be
>   helpful to write security software!

As you can see, using .NET won't really work here. If you still want to try EasyHook, go ahead, but keep the dangers in mind. I'd much more advice you to go and learn C++, and get a deep knowledge of WinApi before attempting anything like a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

[PacketX](http://www.beesync.com/packetx/index.html) is a simple little library to sniff packets.  Not sure if you can completely block the network though.  You'd have to work out a way to disable the network adapter & then make your program appear as the network adapter to forward on the packets as appropriate.

**EDIT:** My bad. "PacketX cannot be used to block network traffic to build a firewall."

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you'll need low-level tools like C++ and WIN API to implement system-level layer of this firewall.